# Memtest86+ won't boot from USB, hangs on GRUB (via Arch), but works on Ubuntu Live USB

Tags: arch-linux, boot, memory, live-usb

I recently ordered some server/workstation RAM that I wanted to test*, but the well-known memory testing methods are giving me a hard time. The only installed OS is Arch Linux. The machine is 13 years old and does not have UEFI, so that's not the issue.

1. First I tried [installing the memtest86+ Arch package as described on the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Stress_testing#Running_Memtest86+). In principle, this works and I can start memtest86+ (5.01) from GRUB. However, it hangs after 1 second once it starts test #2, so this is basically unusable. I tried changing all the settings (by default multi-core is disabled anyways, but still played around with that!), but to no avail. If I skip test #2, test #3 also freezes. *This is probably also the main issue here: How do I get the Arch package method to work? Is this a reportable bug?***
2. Next I tried downloading the memtest86 (v4) and memtest86+ images from the respective websites. I created bootable USBs from them (checked using a different machine, both worked). In this case the server in question won't even recognize the USB as bootable and just skips to HDD booting. This is true for both memtest86 and memtest86+. Disconnecting the HDD makes the boot process hang, understandably.
3. As a last resort, I remembered that Ubuntu Live media include a version of memtest86+ (turns out this is also 5.01, same as the Arch package), so I created an Ubuntu Live USB and tried launching memtest86+ from there. This actually works: It boots, launches and runs without freezing. The tests so far do not indicate any memory failures that might have caused the Arch issues. Note that there is no reason I did not use an Arch Live USB for this, I just didn't know they also included memtest86+ until half an hour ago.

Can anyone explain what's going on here?

*Why I'm even trying to do this, apart from general testing of used hardware: Oddly enough, switching from the old 1 GB sticks to 4 GB sticks seems to slow down the performance as measured by the calculation this machine is intended to run.

**This is also the reason I thought this would be more appropriate for Unix.SE instead of superuser. I might be wrong though!

Comment: Something goes wrong with the memtest versions in Arch, but you found a working method with an Ubuntu live system. I don't know why it does not work in Arch, maybe the menuentry for it is wrong, maybe the firmware or similar for the memory sticks are not doing the job in this computer, but I would not worry much about it because you have a working method. The problem that the 4 GB sticks are slower is a different one, and I suggest that you ask another question about it.

Comment: Are your 1GB and 4GB RAM DIMMS the same speed, or are the 4GB DIMMs slower?   For memory-intensive calculations, this could make a significant difference in performance.   BTW, If your machine is 13 years old, that means it was built in approx 2003, which means it probably had either DDR or DDR2 memory (DDR was introduced in 1998, and DDR2 in 2003).   DDR speeds ranged from ~ 200Mhz to 400Mhz.   and DDR2 speeds ranged from ~400 Mhz to 1066 Mhz.     See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR_SDRAM

Comment: Both DIMMs are PC2-5300F, the only difference is that the older 1 GB's were 2Rx8 while the newer ones are 2Rx4. I had never even heard of the bank specification, and though I tried reading up on it, I didn't quite understand whether this could account for the difference (seemed not so...).